# Parse.com - How to relate whole WordList for all the users in parse.com

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I am making a quiz game and using Parse.com as a backend , I have a WordListSet class with wordId, wordName and isWordUsed. isWordUsed is going to set true or false for the particular user if they have already used that word in the quiz

Now I dont know how to relate whole WordListSet to the UserClass, I did read docs but couldnt understanding the relation mapping thing.

Basically, What I am trying to achieve is say WordListSet has 100 Words for the quiz now whenever the new user is created it will have the whole WordListSet , as user keep on playing I want to keep on setting isWordUser to true so that it cant be reused again.

I need to have mapping with each user otherwise anyuser will once set the isWordUsed to true then other users wont be able to retrieve that word

Answer (score 0):

Use an array they are much simpler than Relations and good for 100 relations.

Add an array to your PFUser subclass and then simply store pointers to the word object here's the Parse docs on one-to-many with Arrays: https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#onetomany

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, Storing Pointers in array to PFUser subclass will point to the actual object of WordListSet, so say if user A has changed isWordUsed to False then next time user B will not be able to use that word since it is set disable ... because the pointer to the word object store in array is pointing to actual object right ?

Comment: so what if i want the copy of whole wordList to be given to each individual user from the WordListSet?.. I mean like our normal programming language where u create new object of class for each individual user ?